# Getting result from db for multiple id for different ranges

Tags: sql

I have in db many ids for timestamps. For example:

```
    id  timestamp  
    1 '2018-11-14 10:00:00'
    2 '2018-11-14 10:00:00'
    3 '2018-11-14 10:00:00'
    4 '2018-11-14 10:00:00'
    1 '2018-11-14 10:01:00'
    2 '2018-11-14 10:01:00'
    3 '2018-11-14 10:01:00'
    4 '2018-11-14 10:01:00'
    1 '2018-11-14 10:02:00'
    2 '2018-11-14 10:02:00'
    3 '2018-11-14 10:02:00'
    4 '2018-11-14 10:02:00'
    1 '2018-11-14 10:03:00'
    2 '2018-11-14 10:03:00'
    3 '2018-11-14 10:03:00'
    4 '2018-11-14 10:03:00'
    1 '2018-11-14 10:04:00'
    2 '2018-11-14 10:04:00'
    3 '2018-11-14 10:04:00'
    4 '2018-11-14 10:04:00'
```

I need to write a query which can select for example id= 2,3 But range of timestamp only from '2018-11-14 10:01:00' till '2018-11-14 10:02:00' including for id 2 and for id 3 from '2018-11-14 10:02:00' till '2018-11-14 10:04:00' 
If it was one record it would be

```
SELECT id, timestamp 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 2 
  AND '2018-11-14 10:01:00' <= timestamp 
  AND timestamp <= '2018-11-14 10:03:00'
```

But what about similar multiple conditions?

UPD: It's not a problem to build query by hands, but id and timestamp I get dynamically, so this query is needed to build dynamically, without knowing id and timestamp before

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Just add all the conditions you want to include.

Comment: Hint:  `id IN (2, 3)`.

Comment: Will IN get me value for 10:04:00?

Comment: `where (id = 2 and timestamp <= ...) or (id = 3 and timestamp <= ...) or (id = 4 and timestamp <= ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a combination of logical operators `AND/OR`:

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM table 
WHERE (id = 2 AND 
       timestamp >= '2018-11-14 10:01:00' AND 
       timestamp <= '2018-11-14 10:02:00') 
      OR 
      (id = 3 AND 
       timestamp >= '2018-11-14 10:02:00' AND 
       timestamp <= '2018-11-14 10:04:00')
```

A neater way of writing it could be using `BETWEEN .. AND ..`:

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM table 
WHERE (id = 2 AND 
       timestamp BETWEEN '2018-11-14 10:01:00' AND '2018-11-14 10:02:00') 
      OR 
      (id = 3 AND 
       timestamp BETWEEN '2018-11-14 10:02:00' AND '2018-11-14 10:04:00')
```

**EDIT** (based on your edit): In order to build your query dynamically, you simply need to use your application code to prepare the query string (eg: in PHP, C++, Java, etc)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I think In won't fit me, because for different ids could be different ranges.

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk then you can use a combination of `AND/OR`. please edit the question to add this case; I will add one more way for this

Comment: edited. I use java, so the problem that different id's could have different ranges, for example id 2 - 10:01 - 10:03; id 3 -10:06 -10:09 and I need get only this rows BUT there also can be id 2 - 10:06-10:09 which I don't need get. Only those two which were specified

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk check the answer. I have given you a general idea. You will need to use the Java code to prepare the query string dynamically; multiple conditions with `OR` in between

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer was very useful, but as I'm using Spring Data JPA,so it is not relevant for me to build dynamically native query. So, I found another solution: 
[Spring Specification](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/). In this link also described Querydsl, but it won't work with current version of lombok (who knows how it will work in future).

So, I've chosen Specification. It gives possibility to build query dynamically:

```
  public class MySpecification<T> {

  public MySpecification(){}

  public Specification<T> hasId(Long id){
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> (criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
  }

  public Specification<T> greaterThan(Timestamp someTimestamp ){
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get("timestamp"), firstDpTimestamp);
  }

  ........


@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

@Override
  public List<MyEntity> getMyEntity(long[] ids, Timestamp[] timestamp) {
        MySpecification<MyEntity> mySpec = new MySpecification<>();
        Specification<MyEntity> spec = where( mySpec.hasId(ids[0]))
            .and(mySpec.greaterThan(timestamp[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < ids.length; i++) {
      spec = spec.or(mySpec.hasId(ids[i]).and(mySpec.greaterThan(timestamp[i]));
    }
    return repo.findAll(spec);
  }
```